# Alias WB name for vlookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to assign an alias to a WB because of its changing name and I need to use this alias in a vlookup. I have used a few examples found online without success.

Here is what I have at this point:

```
' assigns an alias to the workbook since the file name changes
Set AllAcctsWB = ThisWorkbook
AllAcctsWB.Activate

' switches to the correct WB for the vlookup to occur
InfluencerWB.Activate

' counts the number of used rows in this sheet
LastRowA = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

' selects the starting point for the vlokup
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5], '[" & AllAcctsWB & "]Filtered _
    data'!C1:C31,31,0)"

' fills the column to the length of column A
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F" & LastRowA)
```

Any useful advice or guidance is definitely welcome.
In advance, thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I miss the actual problem in your question. You've posted some code, but haven't described what it does, and moreover, what it should do instead. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

`ThisWorkbook` returns a Workbook object corresponding to the current workbook, not the name of the current workbook.

To reference the name of the current workbook, use `ThisWorkbook.Name`

Comment: I need to assign an alias to an open workbook and then be able to use that alias in a vlookup. I appreciate the assistance.